# How to Undo a mirror modifier after applying it?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, mirror, mirror-modifier

So I created eyes using a mirror modifier but realized I need to make separate ones. However, I already applied the mirror modifier previously

Is it possible to un apply it or would I need to recreate new eyes from scratch again?

Comment: If your problem is that you need to separate, why don't you simply separate the 2 meshes as 2 separate objects? (P key)

Comment: ah that is what I was trying to do! is there a difference with having a previous modifier applied before vs just creating new eyes? or any previous applied modifiers won't matter once I separate them?

Comment: You could have simply created your eye and duplicate it. If the copy is supposed to share the same mesh, use Alt D (linked-duplication) instead of Shift D (duplication). If the duplication is symmetrized, use SX-1 (if it is symmetrized on X)

Comment: @moonboots: you could write that as an answer :D

Comment: done..........  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still try to undo with some <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, but if you need to separate the 2 meshes as 2 separate objects, use <kbd>P</kbd> > *Separate Selection*.

You could have simply created your eye and duplicated it. If the copy is supposed to share the same mesh, use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (linked-duplication) instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (duplication). If you want to symmetrize the duplication, use <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> (for a symmetry on X).

Comment: But I I want to symmetrize on w? What can I do then?or should I open a new question for that?

Comment: W is for the time axis, do you want to reverse time? Never do that it's very dangerous!!!!